# Is the Irish English accent derived from the phonetics of the Irish language?

Tags: english, accent, irish

Did Hiberno-English originate as native Irish speakers speaking English from Scotland and England with their native accent, or is it derived from Scots phonetics after the Scots were settled in Ulster?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Hiberno-English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English) has at least part of the answer.